# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.Tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have been building a SharePoint app in the NAPA Office 365 Development Tools. Recently. I wanted to use Visual Studio's debugger so I opened the code in VS. However, when I attempted to compile the code I got the following error:

> Error 2 Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.Tools, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Most everything I've seen told me my problem is that I'm trying to use VS 2010 with SP 2013 however I am currently in VS 2012. Is there a further error I'm unaware of?

<sub>I can add the code, but as it is like 700-900 lines worth of code, so unless people need to see it I was leaving it out.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the office developper tools for VS 2012 ?

Direct download link from MS website:
 http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2012

On my environement, the **Microsoft.Office.Sharepoint.Tools.dll** is deployed in 
*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.Tools\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c*
if you don't have it you are probably missing the developper tools.

Answer (score -1):

You should always download the required SharePoint assemblies onto your build system by copying the following assemblies from the development system to the build system and putting them into a Reference Assembly folder:

- Microsoft.SharePoint.dll Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.dll Microsoft.Office.Server.dll
- Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll
- ***Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.Tools.dll***
- Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.dll Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll

These files are located in the following folder on the development system:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\ISAPI